# Как сделать из android устройства linux сервер?

Tags: android, linux

Нужная информация, как сделать из anroid устройства - сервер. Задача - запускать докер, развернуть apache/nginx и т.д. Есть устройства: 4.2.2, 4.4.2, 6.0 (TWRP), 7.0, 8.0.